# Quartz Scheduler Triggers not respecting priority

Tags: java, triggers, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

Basically, I am using an implementation of Quartz Scheduler and I want multiple jobs to run at the same time but some should run before the others. For this, I have found the parameter "priority" for a Trigger.

SO let's say I have 4 jobs, each with its own trigger. I set the priorities like this:
*job1 - priority 5
job2 - priority 3
job3 - priority 11
job4 - priority 8*

I want them to be run in this order: **job3, job4, job,1, job2**

Out of 20 runs, only around 3 times I get the expected result. For the others, the first task to be run is pretty much random, and the rest are ordered correctly. One run would be like: **job1, job3, job4, job2** OR **job4, job3, job1, job2**

Am I not understanding properly how priorities work in Quartz? I can't find exactly what is happening.

Comment: What is your thread pool size? Do you run in to situation where there are more task to run than available thread..If all the jobs have the same scheduled time and quartz doesnt have free threads to run them all priority kicks in.

Comment: thread pool size is 1. I thought, like in this example http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example14.html that I should be getting the tasks run based on priority no matter what

Comment: We have to look at two things. 1) how your jobs are scheduled? Do you have the same cron  for all jobs and expecting them to fire at the same time or do you use something like intervalWithDelay to schedule multiple runs? 2) Looking at NextFireTime for your jobs might give you more insights. Priorities come into picture only if all jobs are scheduled to fire at the same time. If their fire time are different , the job with the oldest scheduledToFire time will be picked up

Comment: they had the same NextFireTime, I can confirm. I tracked down the problem and posted it as an answer if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that Quartz doesn't ensure that when you schedule multiple jobs at the same time with different priorities, you will get them in the order you want UNLESS you have the working thread already busy. Otherwise, if the working thread is not busy, it will pick up the job with the highest priority that you could schedule in the span of nanoseconds.

For my case, the thread was not busy so while I was scheduling all the jobs, quartz had time to pick up and process the first job I scheduled. The rest of the jobs had time to be scheduled while the thread was busy processing job1.

You guys can follow the message "batch aquisition of..." in order to track  down the problem yourselves.

My solution is to use the method schedule for a List of jobs.